# Create EmailMessage out of Aspose.Net Email MapiMessage?

Tags: exchangewebservices, aspose

Is there a way to create an EWS **EmailMessage** class instance out of Aspose.Net Email **MapiMessage** class instance?

I'm trying to use some common logic for email processing.

1) I have a service processing emails coming to an Exchange folder, and everything works just perfectly.

2) Also, I have users able to upload email files (*.msg) into the web app. These emails are processed using Aspose.Net.Email and I have an instance of **MapiMessage** as an output.

What I can try to do is to use MapiMessage *.ToMailMessage()* method, which will create an instance of **MailMessage** from this MapiMessage. But even after that, I wasn't able to find a way to create an **EmailMessage** to be able to use the processing logic from 1).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have observed your requirements and if I am correctly understanding you are looking for support for interface between Aspose.Email MapiMesaage class and EWS EmailMesage class. These two classes belong to two different APIs and have no interface between them. Aspose.Email for .NET does allow saving as MSG or EML file format and you may load them on your end using EmailMessage class.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage?view=exchange-ews-api

https://apireference.aspose.com/net/email/aspose.email.mapi/mapimessage/constructors/1